# Best way to remove old url links on google index, over 7k of them

Tags: indexing, http-status-code-404

We have recently updated our website and scrapped the old one, however google is still indexing our old web pages over 7,000 of them, including the old sitemap.

How is it possible to de list these from google, They are currently getting 404'd

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: You could have done some url rewriting to redirect the old urls to the new ones. Otherwise, take a look at [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?rd=1).

Comment: Yeah had a read through this, Apart from manually delisting the urls, all I can see online is that they will eventually time out....

Comment: Yes, as the crawlers will keep getting 404, they will eventually delete the urls, unless some external sites are pointing to them (and yet, maybe 404 is a reason for deleting anyway, don't know about that).

Comment: thanks for the reply